# Converting a column-major array for use in a PyPLot histogram

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I'm trying to do some basic image analysis with Julia after observing how much faster it is than Python.

There are good examples out there of how to import a file in using the Images library.  Images reinterprets it then hist changes it to a column-major vector.

```
using Images
img_gld = imread("image.jpg")
img_gld_gs = convert(Image,img_gld)
img_gld_gs = reinterpret(Uint8,data(img_gld_gs))
import PyPlot
h = PyPlot.plt.hist(vec(img_gld_gs), -1:255)
PyPlot.plt.plot(h)
```

The last line is wrong and causing the error :
"INFO: Loading help data...
ERROR: PyError (:PyObject_Call) 
ValueError('setting an array element with a sequence.',)"

How do I correctly pass the data to PyPlot and get the histogram to display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `PyPlot.hist`:

```
using Images, PyPlot
img = imread("image.jpg")
PyPlot.hist(vec(img), -1:255)
```

[image]

Also see the REPL [help mode](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/interacting-with-julia/#help-mode):

```
help> PyPlot.hist
```